# Why isn't my html file not responding?

Tags: html

```
<head>
    <title>Free Jokes!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type = "text/css" src = "final project.css"></style>
</head>
```

I have a separate css file that is validated. But the main reason I think this isn't working is that when I validated the html, it says,"Attribute src not allowed on element style at this point."

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Also any other syntax errors would be much appreciated...

Comment: replace `src` with `href`

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
 <style type = "text/css" src = "final project.css"></style>
```

with:

```
<link href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

have a look at this on how to include css : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <title>Free Jokes!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

Link element uses "href" not "src"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="final project.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

add only `rel` attribute:

`<link type="text/css" href="final project.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

and also avoid using space in file name.